# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Tags: python, disnake

```py
async def accept(inter):
       whitlist_id = data[str(inter.guild.id)]["whitelist"]["active_whitelist"]
       whitlist = bot.get_user(whitlist_id)
       await inter.send(f"<@{whitlist_id}>, вы были приняты!")
       await whitlist.add_roles(1205097011892981811)
       await whitlist.remove_roles(1205235121494560768)
       del data[str(inter.guild.id)]["whitelist"]["active_whitelist"]
       save_db(data=data)
```

и в консоли выдаёт ошибку

```
    await whitlist.add_roles(1205097011892981811)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

библиотека `disnake`

Comment: Похоже, что метод `bot.get_user(whitlist_id)` не нашел пользователя и поэтому вернул None, с которым нельзя производить дальнейшие действия